# Haskell: Parse error in pattern x ++ xs

Tags: haskell, pattern-matching, parse-error

Doing the [third of the 99-Haskell problems](https://wiki.haskell.org/99_questions/1_to_10) (I am currently trying to learn the language) I tried to incorporate pattern matching as well as recursion into my function which now looks like this:

```
myElementAt :: [a] -> Int -> a
myElementAt (x ++ xs) i =
  if length (x ++ xs) == i && length xs == 1 then xs!!0
  else myElementAt x i
```

Which gives me `Parse error in pattern: x ++ xs`. The questions:

1. Why does this give me a parse error? Is it because Haskell is no idea where to cut my list (Which is my best guess)?
2. How could I reframe my function so that it works? The algorithmic idea is to check wether the list has the length as the specified inde; if yes return the last elemen; if not cut away one element at the end of the list and then do the recursion.

Note: I know that this is a really bad algorithm, but it I've set myself the challenge to write that function including recursion and pattern matching. I also tried not to use the `!!` operator, but that is fine for me since the only thing it really does (or should do if it compiled) is to convert a one-element list into that element.

Comment: The pattern-matching issue aside, note that your algorithm is _extremely_ inefficient: `length` already needs to traverse the entire list. If you then recurse on that, you end up with a complexity of _O_ (_n_ ²) for a simple lookup!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Haskell has two different kinds of value-level entities: *variables* (this also includes functions, infix operators like `++` etc.) and *constructors*. Both can be used in expressions, but only constructors can also be used in patterns.

In either case, it's easy to tell whether you're dealing with a variable or constructor: a constructor always starts with an uppercase letter (e.g. [`Nothing`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Data-Maybe.html#v:Nothing), [`True`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/ghc-prim-0.5.0.0/docs/GHC-Types.html#v:True) or [`StateT`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.5.4.0/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-State-Lazy.html#t:StateT)) or, if it's an infix, with a colon (`:`, [`:+`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Data-Complex.html)). Everything else is a variable. Fundamentally, the difference is that a constructor is always a unique, immediately matcheable value from a predefined collection (namely, the alternatives of a `data` definition), whereas a variable can just have *any value*, and often it's *in principle not possible* to uniquely distinguish different variables, in particular if they have a function type.

Yours is actually a good example for this: for the pattern match `x ++ xs` to make sense, there would have to be *one unique way* in which the input list could be written in the form `x ++ xs`. Well, but for, say `[0,1,2,3]`, there are multiple different ways in which this can be done:

```
[] ++[0,1,2,3]
[0] ++ [1,2,3]
[0,1] ++ [2,3]
[0,1,2] ++ [3]
[0,1,2,3]++ []
```

Which one should the runtime choose?

Answer (score 1):

Presumably, you're trying to match the head and tail part of a list. Let's step through it:

```
myElementAt (x:_) 0 = x
```

This means that if the head is `x`, the tail is something, and the index is 0, return the head. Note that your `x ++ x` is a concatenation of two lists, not the head and tail parts.

Then you can have

```
myElementAt(_:tl) i = myElementAt tl (i - 1)
```

which means that if the previous pattern was not matched, ignore the head, and take the *i - 1* element of the tail.

Answer (score 0):

In patterns, you can only use constructors like `:` and `[]`. The append operator `(++)` is a non-constructor function.

So, try something like:

```
myElementAt :: [a] -> Int -> a
myElementAt (x:xs) i = ...
```

There are more issues in your code, but at least this fixes your first problem.

Answer (score 0):

in standard Haskell pattern matches like this :

```
f :: Int -> Int
f (g n 1) = n

g :: Int -> Int -> Int
g a b = a+b
```

Are illegal because function calls aren't allowed in patterns, your case is just a special case as the operator `++` is just a function.

To pattern match on lists you can do it like this:

```
myElementAt :: [a] -> Int -> a
myElementAt (x:xs) i = // result
```

But in this case `x` is of type `a` not `[a]` , it is the head of the list and `xs` is its tail, you'll need to change your function implementation to accommodate this fact, also this function will fail with the empty list `[]`. However that's the idiomatic haskell way to pattern match aginst lists.

I should mention that when I said "illegal" I meant in standard Haskell, there are GHC extensions that give something similar to that , it's called `ViewPatterns` But I don't think you need it especially that you're still learning.